# Combine Function using reduce

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, reduce

I am trying to combine the Function using the reduce function using the code below :

```
class CustomClass {
    private Function<Map<String, String>, Integer> cal;

    public CustomClass (Function<Map<String, String>, Integer>... func) {
        cal = Stream.of(func)
                .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen);
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
The method reduce(Function<Map<String,String>,Integer>, BinaryOperator<Function<Map<String,String>,Integer>>) 
 in the type Stream<Function<Map<String,String>,Integer>> is not applicable 
 for the arguments (Function<Object,Object>, Function::andThen)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only combine two functions if the result of the first matches the argument required by the second. That's not the case in your example, since your `Function`s accept a `Map<String, String>`, but return an `Integer`. You can't pass an `Integer` as an argument to the next `Function`.

If you changed the signature of the `Function`s, your code would pass compilation.

For example:

```
class CustomClass {
    private Function<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>> cal;

    public CustomClass (Function<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>... func) {
        cal =  Stream.of(func)
                .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen);
    }
}
```

and

```
class CustomClass {
    private Function<Integer,Integer> cal;

    public CustomClass (Function<Integer,Integer>... func) {
        cal =  Stream.of(func)
                .reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen);
    }
}
```

both pass compilation.

Comment: Got it, I will change my code as per the requirement

Comment: @vaydesalme Besides the requirement not stated in the question itself. Think of it logically, does it makes sense to chain multiple `Function<Map<String, String>, Integer>` based on their input and output type? Do you even need varargs there?